# How Buffer cache works in oracle database

Tags: oracle

My question is, in Oracle database if there is a 5Gb table and the SGA size is 10GB, if I select the 5Gb table, it will fit into 10GB SGA size.

But if my table is more than 10GB and my SGA size is 5Gb, then how do select queries work, does it display all the rows of 10GB table, and how does the buffer CACHE works?

Comment: In real life you wouldn't select all the columns for all the rows in a 10GB table.  Or if you did you wouldn't do it more than once.

Comment: You should read the section on the SGA in the Database Concepts manual.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/memory.htm#CNCPT802).  You should read all of it, in order to understand the section on *Buffers and Full Table Scans*.

Answer (score 0):

If we have a table which is of more size than than the SGA, then we will have to define the size of SGA again to the required size, and then the problem is solved.

we can define the size of SGA and PGA while creating the database.

**Buffered Cache Working:**

When we request data from disk, at minimum oracle reads one block.Even if we request only one row, many rows in the same table are likely to be retrieved, which lie in the same block. The same goes for column.

A block in the buffered cache can be in one of the three states:

- **Free:** Currently not used.
- **Pinned:** Currently being accessed.
- **Dirty:** Block has been modified but currently not been written to disk.

A block write up is triggered when one of the following happens:

1. The database is issued a shutdown command.
2. A full or partial checkpoint occurs.
3. A recovery time threshold occurs, which is again set by us.
4. A free block is needed and none are found after a given amount of time( we use LRU algorithm here).
5. Certain Data Definition Language commands(DDL).
6. Every three seconds. There are many other reasons, the algorithm is complex and can change with each release of oracle.